# VB6, Setting radiobox value calls RadioButton_Click procedure

Tags: vb6, click, radio-button, procedure

I am using an active X radio box in my software. Whenever I set the value of the radio box, it calls the click function of the radio box, This can cause some delay in loading forms. Is it possible to not allow this?

Thanks!

**edit**

```
Me.TempOpt(1).Value = True
```

When you step into that line, it goes to

```
Private Sub TempOpt_Click(Index As Integer, Value As Integer)
```

Comment: How are you setting the value?  Are you sure there isn't data updated event?

Comment: Me.TempOpt(1).Value = True when you step into that line, it goes to Private Sub TempOpt_Click(Index As Integer, Value As Integer)

Comment: Just add a form level variable which you set to `true` while initializing the form and to `false` afterwards. So you can circumvent undesired events on loading.

Comment: Kind of a hack, use _mouseup instead of _click as a work around

Comment: @MicSim I would post your comment as answer.

Comment: @Brettski: What about people that use the spacebar to toggle a checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is quite common with check boxes and radio buttons. Happens also for normal VB6 controls.

If you have problems while loading the form, just add a form level variable which you set to true while initializing the form and to false afterwards. So you can circumvent undesired events on loading.